# The registration should fail, if the username does not contain only letters

Tags: php, forms

I want to check the username to contain only letters. If it doesn't contain any letters, the registration I want to fail. Is it good to use `preg_match`? Now if I input for `username`: `a1`, also filling the `password`, `confirm password` and `type` fields the registration is successful.

form.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


    /* if the username is alphabetic */

    if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $username)) === false &&!empty($username) ) {
        $errors[] = 'Userame must contain letters and spaces only';
    }

    /* if passwords match */
    if((!empty($password) && !empty($repassword)) && ($password != $repassword)){
        echo "Passwords do not match.";
    }



    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['type'])){


            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, type) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$type')";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            echo 'Successful Registration.';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Please fill all the fields.';
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to limit this?

Comment: Because the username must be only with letters

Comment: while your filtering kinda-sorta-maybe "fixes" the problem, you are still coding in a way that is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and your code blindly assumes queries can never fail. bad bad bad assumption.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Why must it be only letters?

Comment: There must be thousands of scripts out there. You don't need us, *do they Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Nah Ralph*, we certainly aren't needed here @Fred-ii-

Comment: The OP's got something to chew on below *Sam* - @JayBlanchard if that doesn't get their fancy, nothing will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for just letters in the username, `preg_match` will work for you.

For example,

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $username)){
    // if the username has non-letter characters
}
```

However, like the comments are saying, there are much better ways to approach preventing SQL injection attacks. Switching to prepared statements is a great start.